# How to update the map properly using canvas and a button when the players relocate to a new location?

Tags: android-canvas

[My game snapshot Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcgGl.jpg)> Blockquote

> My canvas constructs

```
      public class DrawingView4 extends View{
DrawingView4(Context context4)
{
        super(context4);
}
  @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas4)
{




int tile4=0;

if (DoneDrawFacilities && doneloading) {

    
}
else {
    
    for (int i4=0; i4< 17 && notfixingorientation; i4++){
        if (i4< 16) {
            
            for (int ii4=0; ii4 < 16; ii4++){
                try {
  //Checking the data of all spots of the game map from package directory.
   //Then Draw in canvas if the data of the spot occupied by type of human and core facilities, 
                    FacilityList = new Gson().fromJson(FileUtil.readFile(FileUtil.getPackageDataDir(getApplicationContext()).concat("/GameResource/Tile".concat(String.valueOf((long)(tile4 + 1)).concat(".data")))), new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
                    if (FacilityList.get((int)0).get("Type").toString().equals("Human")) {

             canvas4.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(AllObjects.getString(String.valueOf((long)(tile4)), "")),null,new Rect(ii4*120, i4*120, 120*(ii4+1),120*(i4+1)), null);
                    }
                    if (FacilityList.get((int)0).get("Type").toString().equals("Core")) {
                        if (FacilityList.get((int)0).get("Name").toString().equals("Arena")) {

      canvas4.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(AllObjects.getString(String.valueOf((long)(tile4)), "")),null,new Rect(7*120, 7*120, 120*(8+1),120*(8+1)), null);
                        }
                        else {
                            
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    
                }
                FacilityList.clear();
                tile4++;
                
                
            }
            
        }
        else {
            DoneDrawFacilities = true;
        }
    }
}
}}
```

> Blockquote
> My Relocate button

//I use sharepreference called AllObjects rather than a list and I Only update the path of objects in specific tile in sharedpreference such as in variable 1, 2, etc. and then re-draw using this code below, next time I update the objects path and get this object path from the same json file in the package directory. Too decode to Bitmap and then Draw in canvas.
//Some other code are removed that just updating some data in specific file directory.

```
          AA_structures_facilities.removeAllViews();
         
     AA_structures_facilities.addView(new DrawingView4(GameActivity.this));
```

// But It freezes the screen or stop me from touching the touch event in a second everytime I update new canvas.
//WHILE MY touchevent is hundled in the parent LinearLayout where the canvas is placed.